# How to concat double quotations in variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, string-concatenation

I want to concat `string` variable with double quotation marks. But it seems that when it rendered , the double quotation marks is ignored.`searchString` is the string variable.
See my code below.

```
 "filters={\"name\":" + searchString + "}"
```

Expected result is :

```
"filters={ "name" : "whatever word that holds the search string variable" }"
```

Suggestions pretty much appreciated.

Comment: How about `filters={"name" : searchString}`?

Comment: `{"name": '"' + searchString + '"'}`

Comment: doesn't get my expected results either. but thanks btw :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is already a string.

But in case if you want to append additional quotes then do the following:

```
'"'+stringVariable+'"'
```